# Transaction without 3DS in some online websites is Fraud prone?

Tags: defense, security-theater, fraud

I use my MasterCard credit card for online transactions which uses SecureCode for preventing online frauds even though hackers knows our credit card details.

I have come across many sites which is asking me to enter SecureCode.

But recently i made one transaction in one online website, which is just taken my card details. I was waiting for SecureCode to be entered, but it shows transaction success and I got message money deducted as well.

Why some sites allowed by MasterCard to not required SecureCode ?
what does it mean ? It's more prone to online fraud.. isn't it ?

Using Smart card readers,security tokens we don't need to enter SecureCode i read from wiki, but that article needs citation.
so anyone can clarity me on this. What's happening in transaction ?

Comment: @TildalWave It's not CVV/CVC/CVV2.. I'm talking about SecureCode is a password known to end user.. that is not asking only by few websites.. Why so ?

Comment: Mr.Chowdary - the answer to the question Tildal linked to is the answer to this question. It is exactly the same risk based decision.

Comment: SecureCode is also directly linked to the type of contract subscribed by the store. Low cost contracts do not provide the Secure Code service and the bank provide a low refund in case of non-payment. With higher cost contract, SecureCode is used to lessen the risk so the bank can offer higher assurance level to the store and higher refund in case of fraud.